# Implemeting simple Siemens USS Protocol

Tags: c#, beginner

First of all: I'm completely new to C# and therefore I am not quite sure about the garbage collector. I try to implement the [USS Protocol](https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/253/24178253/att_101238/v1/uss_24178253_spec_76.pdf) by Siemens. 
I tried it this way:

Ready file, byte per byte and pass it to the parsing function USS.RX()

USS.RX(byte ucByte): Message Start -> Should be Startbyte 0x02. If true create a new UssMsg object. Fill the UssMsg object with address, length, function, data and the BCC. If BCC is correct call a user specified event function with the created UssMsg object.

As I switched over from C my inner me says not to do that, as a new object is allocated and then sent over to an event function and then will possibly never been destroyed and creating a huge memory leak? Especially when I start to multitask this?

I would be very thankful for any constructive critic.

Example .USS file: [2016-04-30.rar](https://ufile.io/8a81e)

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace SGAtoUSS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private UInt64 ui64count = 0;
        public Form1()
        {

            byte[] ucData = new byte[1];
            USS.USS_Res ussRes;
            USS oUSS = new USS();
            //Setup UI
            InitializeComponent();
            //Set up new Message Handler
            oUSS.OnNewMessage += new USS.MessageHandler(USSOnNewMsg);
            //Open File
            FileStream USSFile = new FileStream(@"w:\TEMPFEDA\2017-01-16.uss", FileMode.Open);
            //Read and parse file
            while (USSFile.Read(ucData, 0, 1) > 0)
                if ((ussRes = oUSS.RX(ucData)) != USS.USS_Res.OK)
                    Console.WriteLine("ErroR " + ussRes.ToString());


            Console.WriteLine("Done. {0} messages count ", ui64count);
        }
        void USSOnNewMsg(UssMsg ussMsg)
        {
            ui64count++;
            //Console.WriteLine("New Message: " + ussMsg.Function + " Len: " + ussMsg.Length + " BCC: " + ussMsg.BCC);
            //Console.WriteLine("Data: " + BitConverter.ToString(ussMsg.Data));
            //while (true) { }
        }
    }
}
```

USS.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace SGAtoUSS
{
    public class UssMsg : EventArgs
    {
        public byte Length;
        public byte Address;
        public byte Function;
        public byte[] Data;
        public byte BCC;
        public UssMsg()
        {
        }
    }
    class USS
    {
        private const int USS_POS_START = 0;
        private const int USS_POS_Length = 1;
        private const int USS_POS_ADDRESS = 2;
        private const int USS_POS_FUNCTION = 3;
        private const int USS_POS_DATASTART = 4;
        private const int USS_STX = 0x02;

        private enum USS_State
        {
            Start = 1,
            GetLength,
            GetAddress,
            GetFunction,
            GetData
        };

        public enum USS_Res
        {
            OK = 0x00,
            ErrorStart,
            ErrorBCC,
            ErrorUnDef = 0xff
        }
        private byte posBuffRx = 0;


        USS_State ucRxState;
        UssMsg newMsg;

        public delegate void MessageHandler(UssMsg ussMsg);
        public event MessageHandler OnNewMessage;

        public USS()
        {
            posBuffRx = 0;
            ucRxState = USS_State.Start;
        }

        public USS_Res RX(byte ucRxByte)
        {
            USS_Res retVal = USS_Res.OK;
            //switch the states where the current message is right now
            switch (ucRxState)
            {
                case USS_State.Start:
                    //if recved byte is not start byte (0x02) throw exception
                    if (ucRxByte != USS_STX)
                        return USS_Res.ErrorStart;
                    //throw new System.InvalidCastException("Start byte wrong");

                    //otherwise start procedure
                    ucRxState = USS_State.GetLength;
                    posBuffRx = 0;
                    break;
                case USS_State.GetLength:
                    //Create a new UssMsg object
                    newMsg = new UssMsg();

                    newMsg.Length = ucRxByte;
                    //...with a new Data byte array with the length of the message minus the header and the BCC (footer)
                    newMsg.Data = new byte[newMsg.Length - 3];

                    ucRxState = USS_State.GetAddress;
                    break;
                case USS_State.GetAddress:
                    newMsg.Address = ucRxByte;
                    //Address
                    ucRxState = USS_State.GetFunction;
                    break;
                case USS_State.GetFunction:
                    newMsg.Function = ucRxByte;
                    //Function
                    ucRxState = USS_State.GetData;
                    break;
                case USS_State.GetData:
                    if (posBuffRx == newMsg.Length - 3)
                    { //message complete
                        newMsg.BCC = ucRxByte;

                        //TODO: checking BCC will come here
                        OnNewMessage(newMsg);
                        //retVal = USS_Res.NewMsg;
                        //else
                        //  retVal = USS_Res.ErrorBCC; //else return BCC Error

                        //start over next time
                        ucRxState = USS_State.Start;
                    }
                    else { newMsg.Data[posBuffRx++] = ucRxByte; }
                    break;
            }
            return retVal;
        }

        public USS_Res RX(byte[] ucRxBytes)
        {
            USS_Res retVal = USS_Res.OK;
            foreach (byte ucRxByte in ucRxBytes)
            {
                retVal = RX(ucRxByte);
            }
            return retVal;

        }

        private bool BCC(byte[] ucRxBytes)
        {
            return true;//TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Pass by value

**C#** works a bit differently as **plain C** when passing objects to a function.

In **C**, object types are passed by value by default. That means, a shallow copy will be performed on your objects. If you pass a pointer or a reference, you will be able to access and edit the values of the original object.

In **C#**, object types are also passed by value by default. However, if you pass a **class** as parameter, you will be able to edit values within that particular object (basically the same scenario, when you pass a pointer in **C**) since the **object reference** gets passed. If you want your object to be immutable, you will need to implement the [ICloneable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface w/ constructor copying in order to clone it.

### GC

In **C**, if you allocate a chunk of memory, no one will alert you later to delete it and you will leak memory. You will need to get rid of it at some point.

However, **C#** has **Garbage Collector** at its disposal. I will not go into details, there are countless excellent articles about **GC**. Fundamentally, **GC** tracks the valid references of your objects and if there are not any left, **GC** will free the allocated memory space. But, there is **no** guarantee that eg. your local variables will be immediately freed after exiting the scope (in **C**, local variables will be freed upon exiting the scope). When **GC** comes across, it will delete the unused objects and until then they exist as nothing has ever happened. You **can** force **GC** to get rid of your object by calling the [Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) method or using the [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement that destroys the object after exiting its scope.

### Your code

- I would suggest you used a [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of a `FileStream`. It provides a more elegant style with its methods like `ReadByte()` or `ReadInt32()`. There is an example on **MSDN** how to use it with a file input. With this, you could get rid of your single-item byte array declared in the constructor.
- All your processing methods in `USS` could be reworked with the `BinaryReader` to get rid of arrays.
- You shouldn't put any **logic** into the constructor of your `Form`. Put it in a **separate** method and call it. You can also consider using the `FormLoaded` method to be a bit cleaner, but since your logic already goes after `InitializeComponent`, it shouldn't make a big difference.
- Your **const** variables in the `USS` class are unused.
- I might be wrong, but it would be a good idea to stop your code by breaking the `while` cycle whenever your `RX` function returns an error.
- In your `RX(byte[] ucRxBytes)` function, the `foreach` loop could hide errors that occur. *Let's review the following scenario*: we have an array of 3 bytes. We process the first byte, it returns with OK and it gets put into the `retVal` variable. Then, we process the second byte and returns with an ERROR. It also gets put into the `retVal` variable. Finally, we process the third byte and it returns with OK. Guess what, the OK signal gets written to the `retVal` variable and will be returned to your main logic. The error has vanished..
- It is a positive aspect that you use comments. Just the bare things that are mandatory to understand the logic, but nothing more.
- You could consider making your `USS` public, but since the `Form` and `USS` are in the same namespace, it shouldn't matter.
- If you wish to implement this solution in a **multi-threaded** environment, make sure that both the worker and GUI thread are synchronised. GUI thread is only accessible via the `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` methods, otherwise an exception gets thrown.
- If the world of **C** you may have gotten used to working with threads. It's okay to use them in **C#** too, but the [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) async implementation is worth taking a look at. `Task` is really just "a promise of a result in the future" while `Thread` is a lower concept. I would recommend that you use the higher level abstraction wherever you can.

Keep on codin', **C#** is a wonderful language.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this professional answer, I'll keep everything you mentioned in my mind! I'm very satisfied with C# so far. One question to your answer: you are right with the error checking, the Form function was quick and dirty. But as C# uses exceptions for error handling should I also throw an exception when I code routines by myself? Or should I use return values as like as the code above?